# Change navigation component depending on what page user is on

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using transparent navigation bar in vue app. The aim is to have different color links depending on what page a user is on. I am using `vue-router` and a separate navbar(navigation) component.

I have different background color for different pages, for example the home page has a dark grey background whereas the contact page has white background, and navbar is fixed top, so I want to have a dark colored navbar links when the background of the page is light and vice-versa.

This is how components are used on home page and contact page

```
Home
 -navbar
 -hero
 -content
 -footer

Contact
 -navbar
 -contact form
 -footer
```

So, is there a way to tell navbar to have different link color when on contact page vs home page?

Comment: Could you help me understand what you mean by change link colors? Do you just want a way to highlight the link corresponding to the current route the user is on?

Comment: @SerShubham I have different background color for different pages, for example the home page has a dark grey background whereas the contact page has white background, and navbar is fixed top, so I want to have a dark colored navbar links when the background of the page is light and vice-versa

Comment: Ahhh. I understand. Let me help you out with a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `vue-router`, the current route that the user is on is accessible from the variable: `this.$route.path`. For example, if your user is on the Home route, the value in the variable may be: `/home`.

You can use this to dynamically change the color of your navbar:

```
//in your navbar.vue (navbar component)

<template>
   <div v-bind:class="{color: navBarColor}">
   </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
   computed: {
      navBarColor() {
         if (this.$route.path === "/home") { // if it is a dark route
            return "#fff"; // basically any light color you want
         }
         return "#000"; // the dark color of your choice.
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

This should work for now. Going forward, I would recommend using the `meta` key allowed in the vue router. You can set custom meta fields for each route using this.

Check: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/meta.html

Your component would then look something like this:

```
//router.vue

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/home', //the one with the dark background
      component: Home,
      meta: { navBarColor: '#fff' }
    }
  ]
});
```

```
// navbar.vue


<template>
   <div v-bind:class="{color: navBarColor}">
   </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
   computed: {
      navBarColor() {
        return this.$route.meta.navBarColor
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Any one of the two approaches should help you out :)